# Shopping Cart strictly using session or cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net

Well being a total newbie to ASP.NET, I just want some heads up that how can I develop a simple shopping cart just using cookies or session. Just to give some idea, I am having just four items as a sample in my demo cart. Any heads up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad. Do some research on the topic and come back with a more specific question to get more results.

Comment: This is kind of of an advanced topic for a self-professed newbie ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broad question begs a broad answer, so here's roughly how you could do it.

1. Add a [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) to your main ASPX form containing each shopping cart item, plus an "Add" [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx).
2. On page load event in the code-behind, check if the request is a postback (ie, the user clicked "add") using *Page.IsPostBack*.
3. It it is a postback, then retrieve the product ID from the DropDownList.
4. Finally, add or update the [Session](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/) object to contain the user's shopping cart.  Use *if (Session["Cart"]==null)* to check if there's already a cart.  If not, create it by using this:

.

```
List<string> newCart = new List<string>();
newCart.Add(newProductId);
Session["Cart"] = newCart;
```

Here the cart is represented as a simple list of product IDs (strings).

Comment: Will definitely try to do this :) Thanks!